# How to get a a single substring value from an object's property?

Tags: javascript, arrays, substring

I have an array of objects. Each object has a date property. From that date, I'm trying to pull out and display only the year for that property.

As you can see when you run the script, it displays all the years for each object. How do I tie it to the individual object?

```js
//array of objects
objArray = [
  {
    foo: 1,
    bar: "December 5, 2020"
  },
  {
    foo: 3,
    bar: "April 2, 2019"
  },
  {
    foo: 5,
    bar: "January 6, 2018"
  }
];

//get year from date
let result = objArray.map((a) => a.bar.substr(-4));

//template literal
function objArrayTemplate(obj) {
  return `
    <p>Item ${obj.foo}</p>
    <p>Year: ${result}</p>
    <p>***********</p>
  `;
}

//output
document.getElementById("objArrayResult").innerHTML = `${objArray
  .map(objArrayTemplate)
  .join(" ")}`;
```

```html
<div id="objArrayResult"></div>
```

Comment: `<p>Year: ${result}</p>` -> `<p>Year: ${obj.bar.substr(-4)}</p>`

Comment: I really over-complicated that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Just extract the year inside the `objArrayTemplate` function.

```js
//array of objects
objArray = [
  {
    foo: 1,
    bar: "December 5, 2020"
  },
  {
    foo: 3,
    bar: "April 2, 2019"
  },
  {
    foo: 5,
    bar: "January 6, 2018"
  }
];

//template literal
function objArrayTemplate(obj) {
  return `
    <p>Item ${obj.foo}</p>
    <p>Year: ${obj.bar.substr(-4)}</p>
    <p>***********</p>
  `;
}

//output
document.getElementById("objArrayResult").innerHTML = `${objArray
  .map(objArrayTemplate)
  .join(" ")}`;
```

```html
<div id="objArrayResult"></div>
```

Comment: @JaredNewnam Please see if this solves your problem, do let me know if you have any issues.

Answer (score -1):

You should use new Date() to get the timestamp and then get the full year from that timestamp

Here is the working codes

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="objArrayResult"></div>
    <script>
        //array of objects
        objArray = [
            {
                foo: 1,
                bar: new Date(),
            },
            {
                foo: 3,
                bar: new Date(),
            },
            {
                foo: 5,
                bar: new Date(),
            },
        ];

        // template literal
        function objArrayTemplate(obj) {
            return `
                <p>Item ${obj.foo}</p>
                <p>Year: ${obj.bar.getFullYear()}</p>
                <p>***********</p>
            `;
        }

        // output;
        document.getElementById("objArrayResult").innerHTML = `${objArray
            .map(objArrayTemplate)
            .join(" ")}`;
    </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: These are supposed to be varying dates that I manually enter, as shown in the OP. Why would you change my requirements?

Comment: @JaredNewnam Using a Date object (or timestamp) isn't a bad suggestion; It will offer you a lot more flexibility in the future (e.g. extracting the day and month).

Comment: Timestamp gives you more than your own date, but if you want to use your specified data, you can use them as well and convert them into timestamp to get more details

Comment: But these are not timestamps generated from a database. These are dates that I manually enter into the object. Every object is a news article. Each news article has it's own date. Using a date object here wouldn't help me because I have specific dates I need to enter for each article. 

If I'm understanding you wrong, please explain but use the dates I've specified in the OP.

Comment: @Issa - I meant to follow up. I did try this method and it works fine. The thing is that even though I need to pull out just the year, I still need to display the date in the format `December 5, 2020`. Does that make sense?

Comment: @JaredNewnam Yeah it makes sense. But getting year by just substracting strings isn't good approach, it's hard coding. You can generate the timestamp by passing your date into new Date(your_specific_time) and use timestamp to get what you want but not subtract your strings. You can reffer to this link [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Comment: You can also refer to [javascript.info](https://javascript.info/date)